# Scheme pattern matching with match-lambda

Tags: scheme, pattern-matching, racket

I am writing a function called annotate that uses match-lambda, often with recursive calls to annotate.  Here is one of the pattern matches:

```
(`(lambda (,<param1> . ,<params>) ,<stmts>)
        `(CLOSURE ENV (,<param1> . ,<params>) `(lambda (ENV) ,(map annotate ,(list-append `(,<param1> . ,<params>) `(,<stmts>))))))
```

list-append just makes new lists out of its two arguments.  The problem is that when this pattern matches it returns something like:

```
'(CLOSURE
  ENV
  (x)
  `(lambda (ENV)
     ,(map
       annotate
       (<results of list-append>))))
```

Specifically, ",(map annotate" prints literally rather than being evaluated -- even though it is being unquoted.  Other patterns within the function appear to use the exact same syntax without this issue.  Also, the unquoted function list-append executes with no problems.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have nested backquotes: you have one in front of `CLOSURE` and then a second one in front of the second `lambda` without a comma in between: notice the literal backquote in the middle of your output.  I think removing the backquote before the second `lambda` will fix the problem.

Comment: I tried that and it complains that the unquote before "(list-append" is not in a quasi-quote.

Comment: You need to remove the comma there; `map annotate` will be outside of a quasiquote (since you want to run it), so you do not need to unquote things inside it.

Comment: Ah, list-append does not need to be unquoted afterall.  Thanks again.